# CSS width=auto is restricted by parent.wadth

Tags: javascript, css

Setting width=auto doesn't seem to have the intended result when the element is a child of another element.  See example below - you can see that "Test one" and "Test two" have their widths restricted by the width of their parent div's but "Test three" adjusts it's width correctly as it is not a child but an adjacent sibling of it's related div.

```css
div { background: lightGrey; }

div span { background: beige; }

.tooltip {
 position: relative; 
 display: inline-block;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .ttPopup, .tooltip + .ttPopup {
 display: inline-block;
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 width: auto;
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
 background-color: beige;
 border: solid 1px cyan;
 text-align: center;
}

.tooltip + .ttPopup {
 left: 8%;
 top: 20%;
}

.tooltip:hover .ttPopup, .tooltip:hover + .ttPopup { visibility: visible; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="tooltip">Test one
 <span class="ttPopup">line 1<br>line 2<br>line 3<br>line 4<br>line 5</span>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="tooltip">Test two
 <span class="ttPopup">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  <br>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
  <br>eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  <br> et dolore magna aliqua.
 </span>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="tooltip">Test three
</div>
<span class="ttPopup">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  <br>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
  <br>eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  <br> et dolore magna aliqua.
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `width: auto` makes the element expand to occupy all available horizontal space within its containing block.
If it has any horizontal padding or border, the widths of those do not add to the total width of the element.

A parent DIV element would be considered a "containing block", and `auto` will not expand beyond that block, only up to the block if the content requires it to.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is define `width` of child element. e.g. I have defined the width of child element to `width: 300px` and it seems to properly taking `width`. See if this helps you -

```css
div { background: lightGrey; }

div span { background: beige; }

.tooltip {
 position: relative; 
 display: inline-block;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .ttPopup, .tooltip + .ttPopup {
 display: inline-block;
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
 background-color: beige;
 border: solid 1px cyan;
 text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}

.tooltip + .ttPopup {
 left: 8%;
 top: 20%;
}

.tooltip:hover .ttPopup, .tooltip:hover + .ttPopup { visibility: visible; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="tooltip">Test one
 <span class="ttPopup">line 1<br>line 2<br>line 3<br>line 4<br>line 5</span>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="tooltip">Test two
 <span class="ttPopup">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  <br>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
  <br>eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  <br> et dolore magna aliqua.
 </span>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="tooltip">Test three
</div>
<span class="ttPopup">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  <br>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
  <br>eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  <br> et dolore magna aliqua.
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Or

You can simply add `position: absolute` child and no position to parent
then css for parent and child element will look something like -

```
.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .ttPopup, .tooltip + .ttPopup {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: beige;
  border: solid 1px cyan;
  text-align: center;
  left: 8%;  
}
```

I hope this will help you in some way (y).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions pradeep1991singh.

The first way you suggest does indeed work but only for a fixed width popup, I was hoping to find some way to have automatic width sizing as per Test three.

Your second suggestion has the problem that the position of the popup in completely decoupled from the original link, the idea is to have the popup appear right next to the original link.